# JOOQ Cannot get autoCommit to a PostgreSQL database

Tags: postgresql, jooq, autocommit

I have the following setup where a service layer, using `jooq`, contacts a PostgreSQL database.

In this scenario, whenever multiple requests happen quickly one after another (or even not that quickly), I get the following error message:

`Internal error processing createItem: Cannot get autoCommit`

My queries all run within transactions (using `jooq`'s `transactionResult` methods).

Searching has not yielded many results, and I do not see why `autoCommit` should even be enabled in those cases. Is this most likely a configuration issue, or is there something else I can try to troubleshoot this issue better?

Comment: Can you show 1) your jOOQ code and 2) how you configure the jOOQ `Configuration` and/or your datasource / connection?

Answer (score -1):

I noticed the same problem and message when running massive batch uploads on the limit of physical memory and limited amount of db connection (specific to my environment). It would be hard to provide a reproduction case for that, but to me this is a sign of db performance/memory starvation. Reduction of Java execution threads helped in my case.